# Why Opencl kernel runs on Intel HD much faster than NVIDIA GeForce?

Tags: profiling, opencl, nvidia

My laptop has a GeForce 960M GTX and an Intel HD 530. I am running a kernel and using the following code to use the profiler of openCL:

```
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, voxelization_kernel, 1, NULL, &processed_global_size,
        &local_size, 0, NULL, &kernel_event);
err = clWaitForEvents(1, &kernel_event);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(kernel_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,
        sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(kernel_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,
        sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
    elapsed_time = time_end - time_start;
    printf("Elapsed time in kernel: %f ms\n", (float)(time_end - time_start)/(float)1000000);
```

The elapsed time on Intel is up to 10X faster than GeForce. For example for a kernel that takes 12.519104ms on GeForce, the elapsed time on Intel HD is just 1.427828ms. Same pattern exists for other datasets. This looks pretty strange to me because GeForce was supposed to be a much better device. Am I doing something wrong in profiling or is there something that I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Performance is sensitive to workgroup size, memory access patterns, etc, which you didn't specify in your question. The topic is very broad for a simple answer.  You can try first to run a 3rd party OpenCL benchmark on both of your devices, and compare the result, to have a baseline of your expectations.

Answer (score -1):

> For example for a kernel that takes 12.519104ms on GeForce, the
>   elapsed time on Intel HD is just 1.427828ms.

in light of the foregoing, Intel HD is much closer to CPU and has less latency for calculations like

> c[i]=a[i]+b[i]

for example or linear complexity algorithms like voxelization where data is not re-used in device memory or is read/written only once by each thread.

- distance related low access latency for igpu
- memory path related zero copy for igpu
- algorithm complexity